# Geoserver outputs latin1, even though utf-8 is set as encoding

Tags: geoserver, encoding

I've been told, by the administrator, that this geoserver is outputting utf-8:
http://wfs-kbhkort.kk.dk/web/, however I can only get good results when parsing WFS from latin1 to utf-8. Can anyone confirm that the geoserver is correctly outputting utf-8 or confirm that it is latin1. If it is latin1, then how can I tell the administrator to change it to utf-8?

I know this perhaps is a rather odd question, but I'm very new to geoserver (and GIS in general)...

Comment: Maybe its far of, but could it be your request that is formatted to *latin1* and thus the GeoServer responds in *latin1*?

Comment: Maybe :) This is my request: http://wfs-kbhkort.kk.dk/k101/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=k101:betalingszone&outputFormat=csv&SRSNAME=EPSG:4326

Comment: I cannot determine the encoding of your request. *You* have to determine how you encode the request you send to the GeoServer.

Comment: I'm using python's requests library for getting results. This is my code:

        res = requests.get(url, timeout=url_timeout)

I guess this is somewhat out of the scope of this forum...?

Comment: You might wan't to search in or ask a question at http://www.stackoverflow.com regarding encoding, `python` and the `requests` library. Encoding can be very tricky.

Comment: I've asked in stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19563494/python-requests-encoding-does-not-encode-content